# Can't import a .html URL into Google Sheets?

Tags: html, json, google-sheets, split, importerror

What I am trying to archive is import the first row (excluding header) from this URL:
https://colintalkscrypto.com/cbbi/table.html

IMPORTDATA bring in all the html code and IMPORTHTML doesn't work as it's looking for the actual table from https://colintalkscrypto.com/cbbi/

There is also a JSON URL which is the same data but no luck with that either

https://colintalkscrypto.com/cbbi/data/latest.json

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(IMPORTDATA("https://colintalkscrypto.com/cbbi/data/latest.json"), ":"), "offset 2", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah this worked... however just want the last row

Comment: And when I say last row, there are alot of empty cells in the list I need the absolute last row? Is there a way to possiblely importdata in asc/desc order and grab the first row?

Comment: @Bassik try: `=INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT(IMPORTDATA("https://colintalkscrypto.com/cbbi/data/latest.json"), ":"), SEQUENCE(COUNTA(IMPORTDATA("https://colintalkscrypto.com/cbbi/data/latest.json")))}, "select Col1,Col2 where Col1 is not null order by Col3 desc limit 1", 0))`

Comment: Awesome that worked... I did manage to work it out as well with:
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(IMPORTDATA("https://colintalkscrypto.com/cbbi/data/latest.json"), ":"), "SELECT * order by Col1 desc limit 13", 0)) which gave me the first row of all metrics